# detailTextLabel not showing even after setting style to subtitle

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have got this Swift code in my project

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellid, for: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellid)
    }
    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    cell!.textLabel?.text=user.Name
    cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = user.Email
    return cell!
}
```

Everything works fine except that detaiTextLabel is not showing.What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Do you have prototype cell?

Comment: @RajeshkumarR are you talking about class used in `tableView.register(UserCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellid)`?

Comment: Do you have UserCell in storyboard?

Comment: @RajeshkumarR no i don't use storyboard

Comment: Check the tableview cell using Debug View Hierarchy

Comment: @RajeshkumarR detailTextLabel is not showing there either

Comment: Note that your `if` statement will never be true.

Comment: change Storyboard prototype cell and changing the value of the detailTextLabel

Answer (score 1):

My problem was in

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
```

I should have set style to `subtitle` like this

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is its not going inside **if** condition where you mentioned .subTitle. So I tried of removing **if** condition it and its working.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellid, for: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell

     cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellid)

    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    cell!.textLabel?.text=user.Name
    cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = user.Email
    return cell!
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The text in detailTextLabel won't show up if your string is too long to fit inside the label's width. You have 2 options, reduce the size of your string or the font size.

Comment: `I@mail.ru` is too long?

Comment: Try swapping it out with 'test' or something short. Then try reducing the font size and see if it shows up. In my experience, that's always resolved the issue.

Comment: If you can send me your code, I will look and run some tests in an hour or so.

Comment: Where should i send it to you>

Comment: Can you post it to Dropbox so I can pull it down?

Comment: Cool, happy to hear!